# django-jsonforms how to remove the Json: label for the jsonschemaform field?

Tags: json, django, django-forms, jsonschema

I'm using django-jsonforms. I'm trying to remove the "Json:" in the picture.

[image: how remove the "Json:" label?]

```
b =  {
     "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "Products": {
          "type": "array",
          "products": {
              "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 0,
          "maxItems": 5,
      }
  }
}
```

I already tried the `self.fields["form"].label = "myform"` and change widget, and put "label", "ui:label" etc. in the schema.
I can't find anything in the docs.?

Answer (score 0):

**In forms.py**

```
from django_jsonforms.forms import JSONSchemaField
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    options = {"no_additional_properties": True,
               "disable_collapse": True,
               "disable_edit_json": True,
               "disable_properties": True,
               }

    form = JSONSchemaField(schema='schema/schema.json', options=options, ajax=False)
    form.label = ''
```

**In html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}
    {{ form.media }}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```